# Send tap input faster to my Android phone

Tags: c#, android

i currently have an app that is using ADB to send tap inputs to my phone im looking for a way to send them faster how ever. right now i can send a tap about every .750 seconds and i would like to up that by like a lot. The current problem is that if i go much about .600 the phone starts to freeze up so im wondering if there is a way to send taps more efficiently.

```
class Program
{
    static bool run = true;
    static bool wait = false;
    static int Xr = 480;
    static int Yr = 800;
    static int Rx = 0;
    static int Ry = 0;
    static int tapRate = 600;
    static string ADBLocation = @"C:\Users\PATH\Downloads\ADB";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting Resolution...");
        setResolution();
        Console.WriteLine("Resolution set to X: {0} Y: {1}",Rx,Ry);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please set a Tap rate (Milliseconds)");
        tapRate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.ReadKey();
        Thread th = new Thread(thread);
        th.Start();
        while (run)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stop Clicking?");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Stop");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Pause");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Video");
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    run = false;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    wait = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press anything to Continue");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    wait = false;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    wait = true;
                    video();
                    wait = false;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    wait = true;
                    getScreenCap();
                    wait = false;

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    public static int getX(int X)
    {
        return (int)(((double)X / (double)Xr) * (double)Rx);
    }
    public static int getY(int Y)
    {
        return (int)(((double)Y / (double)Yr) * (double)Ry);
    }
    public static void anilizeImage()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        using (Image d = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.png", ADBLocation)))
        {
            d.Save(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.bmp", ADBLocation), ImageFormat.Bmp);

            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.bmp", ADBLocation)))
            {
                Color[] color = new Color[5];
                color[0] = bmp.GetPixel(getX(250), getY(500));
                color[1] = bmp.GetPixel(getX(250), getY(505));
                color[2] = bmp.GetPixel(getX(250), getY(495));
                color[3] = bmp.GetPixel(getX(255), getY(500));
                color[4] = bmp.GetPixel(getX(245), getY(500));

                Color item = color[0];
                {
                    if (item.R != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.B != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.G != 80)
                        return;
                }
                item = color[1];
                {
                    if (item.R != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.B != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.G != 80)
                        return;
                }
                item = color[2];
                {
                    if (item.R != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.B != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.G != 80)
                        return;
                }
                item = color[3];
                {
                    if (item.R != 8)
                        return;
                    if (item.B != 147)
                        return;
                    if (item.G != 127)
                        return;
                }
                item = color[4];
                {
                    if (item.R != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.B != 80)
                        return;
                    if (item.G != 80)
                        return;
                }
                wait = true;
                video();
                wait = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setResolution()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png",ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe pull /sdcard/screencap.png {0}", ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell rm -r /sdcard/screencap.png", ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        using (Image d = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.png", ADBLocation)))
        {
            Ry=d.Height;
            Rx = d.Width;
        }
    }

    public static void getScreenCap()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png", ADBLocation);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe pull /sdcard/screencap.png {0}", ADBLocation);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell rm -r /sdcard/screencap.png", ADBLocation);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            anilizeImage();
            File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.png", ADBLocation));
            File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.bmp", ADBLocation));
        }
        catch
        {
            if (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.png", ADBLocation)))
                File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.png", ADBLocation));
            if (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.bmp", ADBLocation)))
                File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\screencap.bmp", ADBLocation));
        }
    }

    public static void uplock()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\PATH\Downloads\ADB\adb.exe shell input keyevent 26";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\PATH\Downloads\ADB\adb.exe shell input swipe 300 500 300 150";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }

    public static void video()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {2}\adb.exe shell input tap {0} {1}",getX(300),getY(500),ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked Video Button");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 45 seconds");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(45000);
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell input keyevent 4", ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Back Button Clicked");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 10 seconds");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {0}\adb.exe shell input keyevent 4",ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Back Button Clicked");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 2 seconds");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {2}\adb.exe shell input tap {0} {1}",getX(250),getY(500),ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

    }

    public static void thread()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {2}\adb.exe shell input tap {0} {1}",getX(250), getY(120),ADBLocation);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        DateTime shadow = new DateTime();
        DateTime screencap = DateTime.Now;
        while(run)
        {
            while (wait)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(tapRate);
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} launched", i);
            if (screencap.AddMinutes(2) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                Thread cap = new Thread(getScreenCap);
                cap.Start();
                screencap = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (shadow == new DateTime() || shadow.AddMinutes(10) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {2}\adb.exe shell input tap {0} {1}", getX(140), getY(680), ADBLocation);
                shadow = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c {2}\adb.exe shell input tap {0} {1}", getX(250), getY(120), ADBLocation);
            }
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

        }
    }
}
```